# Android: faultactor: 'null' detail error while calling webservice

Tags: android, web-services, null, asmx, android-ksoap2

I am developing an application which gets location details from the android and send it to the vb.net webservice for inserting it into the database.
When I am accessing the localhost webservice for testing purpose, I am successfully inserting the location details to the database.
But when I call the actual webserver i.e http://www.enoxonline.in/webservice.asmx?op=SetLocationForAndroid, I am getting the following exception.

```
05-27 12:21:37.477: I/System.out(276): SetLocationForAndroid{Latitude=37.422005; Longitude=-122.084095; sAddress=Charleston Road, Mountain View, San Jose; sLocality=California; sCountry=United States; sUserId=1004; }
05-27 12:21:39.998: E/Error :(276): Exception: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
05-27 12:21:39.998: E/Error :(276):    at WebService.SetLocationForAndroid(String Latitude, String Longitude, String sAddress, String sLocality, String sCountry, String sUserId)
05-27 12:21:39.998: E/Error :(276):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
05-27 12:21:39.998: W/System.err(276): SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
05-27 12:21:40.008: W/System.err(276):    at WebService.SetLocationForAndroid(String Latitude, String Longitude, String sAddress, String sLocality, String sCountry, String sUserId)
05-27 12:21:40.008: W/System.err(276):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@43e626e0
```

I went through so many posts, but I did not get the clear idea about the problem/
Can someone please tell me what is the wrong ?

My Webservice code:

```
<WebMethod()> _
    Public Function SetLocationForAndroid(ByVal Latitude As String, ByVal Longitude As String, ByVal sAddress As String, ByVal sLocality As String, ByVal sCountry As String, ByVal sUserId As String) As String

        Dim sdr As New DataSet()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Dim dl As New DL.clsDataLayer
        Dim strquery As String

        Dim sLatitude As Double = CDbl(Latitude)
        Dim sLongitude As Double = CDbl(Longitude)

        'Dim longitude = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng").InnerText
        Try
            With dl
                '.SqlQuery = "INSERT INTO MAP (LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,SERVER_DATE,ADDRESS,LOCALITY,COUNTRY,USER_ID,WEB_ENTRY) VALUES (" + dLatitude.ToString() + "," + dLongitude.ToString() + ",getdate(),'" + sAddress.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + sLocality.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + sCountry.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + sUserId + "',0 )"
                .SqlQuery = "INSERT INTO MAP (LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,SERVER_DATE,ADDRESS,LOCALITY,COUNTRY,USER_ID,WEB_ENTRY) VALUES (" + sLatitude.ToString + "," + sLongitude.ToString + ",getdate(),'" + sAddress.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + sLocality.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + sCountry.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + sUserId + "',0 )"
                strquery = "INSERT INTO MAP (LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,SERVER_DATE,ADDRESS,LOCALITY,COUNTRY,USER_ID,WEB_ENTRY) VALUES (" + sLatitude.ToString + "," + sLongitude.ToString + ",getdate(),'" + sAddress.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + sLocality.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + sCountry.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + sUserId + "',0 )"
                sdr = .fnGetData
            End With
            Return strquery

            'Dim conn As New SqlConnection
            'conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = 62.75.229.51; Initial Catalog = Silver_WebPH; User id =Silver_Webph; password =sbyadmin1"
            'Dim strSql As String = "INSERT INTO MAP (LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,SERVER_DATE,ADDRESS,LOCALITY,COUNTRY,USER_ID,WEB_ENTRY) VALUES (" + sLatitude.ToString + "," + sLongitude.ToString + ",getdate(),'" + sAddress.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + sLocality.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + sCountry.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + sUserId + "',0 )"
            'conn.Open()
            'Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
            'cmd.Connection = conn
            'cmd.CommandText = strSql
            'cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            'cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            'Return True
        Catch ioEx As IO.IOException
            ' Handle other non-specific IO Exceptions here.
            Throw New Exception(ioEx.Message.ToString)
        Return strquery     
            'Return ioEx.Message.ToString

        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Handle any other non-IO Exception here.
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message.ToString)
        Return strquery     
            'Return ex.Message.ToString
        End Try

    End Function
```

My Android code which calls the webservice...

```
private String sendLocation(String latitude, String longitude, String sAddress, String sLocality, String sCountry, String sUserId)
    {
/*      final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:25722/NewLocationMap/Service.asmx";
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/SetLocationForAndroid";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "SetLocationForAndroid";
*/  
        final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.enoxonline.in/";
        final String URL = "http://www.enoxonline.in/webservice.asmx";
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/SetLocationForAndroid";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "SetLocationForAndroid";     

        try
        {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject (NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
            pi.setType(String.class);
            pi.setName("Latitude");
            pi.setValue(latitude);
            request.addProperty(pi);
//          request.addProperty("Latitude",latitude);
            pi = new PropertyInfo();
            pi.setType(String.class);
            pi.setName("Longitude");
            pi.setValue(longitude);
            request.addProperty(pi);
//          request.addProperty("Longitude", longitude);
            pi = new PropertyInfo();
            pi.setType(String.class);
            pi.setName("sAddress");
            pi.setValue(sAddress);
            request.addProperty(pi);
//          request.addProperty("Longitude", longitude);
            pi = new PropertyInfo();
            pi.setType(String.class);
            pi.setName("sLocality");
            pi.setValue(sLocality);
            request.addProperty(pi);
//          request.addProperty("Longitude", longitude);
            pi = new PropertyInfo();
            pi.setType(String.class);
            pi.setName("sCountry");
            pi.setValue(sCountry);
            request.addProperty(pi);
//          request.addProperty("Longitude", longitude);
            pi = new PropertyInfo();
            pi.setType(String.class);
            pi.setName("sUserId");
            pi.setValue(sUserId);
            request.addProperty(pi);
//          request.addProperty("sUserId", UserId);


            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet=true;
            envelope.xsd = NAMESPACE;
            envelope.enc = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Entity";
            envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
            envelope.implicitTypes = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            System.out.println(request);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            return envelope.getResponse().toString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("Error : " , "Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return ex.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are getting nullpoinret in the webservice..try to debug it..

Comment: the webservice is not under my control, Its a working website...
is there any other way ?